# Using align* and array together to show relationship between matrix and system

Tags: equations, align, matrices, arrays

I am trying to align an entire matrix with a system of equations with an arrow between them. Here is what I have so far,

```
\begin{align*}
    \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1 & 0 & 0 & \redtt{b1}  \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & \redtt{b2}  \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & \redtt{b3} 
    \end{array}\right] \longrightarrow && \\
        && x &= \redtt{b1} \\
        && y + z &= \redtt{b2} \\
        && z &= \redtt{b3}
\end{align*}
```

and it is producing the image below. I would like it to be all inline with itself. Any help would be greatly appreciated. \redtt is just a shortcut I made. It is equivalent to `\newcommand{\redtt}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\texttt{#1}}}`

[image]

Comment: Will there be more than one "block" in vertical alignment?  If not, it would be better to use `\[...\]` or `equation*` (or forget the `*` if you would like this numbered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please consider posting complete examples such that others do not have to reverse engineer commands like `\redtt`. As for your question, you can use `aligned` or an `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\redtt}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\mathtt{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1 & 0 & 0 & \redtt{b1}  \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & \redtt{b2}  \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & \redtt{b3} 
    \end{array}\right]\quad \longrightarrow\quad \begin{aligned}
        x &= \redtt{b1} \\
        y + z &= \redtt{b2} \\
        z &= \redtt{b3}\\
    \end{aligned} \\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1 & 0 & 0 & \redtt{b1}  \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & \redtt{b2}  \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & \redtt{b3} 
    \end{array}\right]\quad \longrightarrow\quad \begin{array}{@{}r<{{}}@{}>{{}}l@{}}
        x &= \redtt{b1} \\
        y + z &= \redtt{b2} \\
        z &= \redtt{b3}
    \end{array} \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

IMHO `aligned` looks better but in the array you maintain the same spacing between the rows as in the matrix. (Of course one can adjust `aligned` to give the same spacing, and so on.)

**ADDENDUM**: As barbara beeton points out, if you only have a one-line equation it is more appropriate to use `\[...\]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\redtt}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\mathtt{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[
    \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1 & 0 & 0 & \redtt{b1}  \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & \redtt{b2}  \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & \redtt{b3} 
    \end{array}\right]\quad \longrightarrow\quad \begin{aligned}
        x &= \redtt{b1} \\
        y + z &= \redtt{b2} \\
        z &= \redtt{b3}\\
    \end{aligned} 
\]
or
\[
    \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1 & 0 & 0 & \redtt{b1}  \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & \redtt{b2}  \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & \redtt{b3} 
    \end{array}\right]\quad \longrightarrow\quad \begin{array}{@{}r<{{}}@{}>{{}}l@{}}
        x &= \redtt{b1} \\
        y + z &= \redtt{b2} \\
        z &= \redtt{b3}
    \end{array} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even think to use aligned. I was trying to nest another align* in there but it didn't like that of course.

Comment: See my comment on the question regarding use of `align` for "one-line" displays.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, this is a good point.

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply use a single column array (and avoid pure colors):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\redtt}[1]{\textcolor{red!90!blue}{\mathtt{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc|c@{}}
  1 & 0 & 0 & \redtt{b1}  \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & \redtt{b2}  \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & \redtt{b3} 
\end{array}\right]
\;\longrightarrow\;
\begin{array}{@{}r@{}}
      x = \redtt{b1} \\
  y + z = \redtt{b2} \\
      z = \redtt{b3}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]